# Transfer between integrals and infinite sums

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

So I was watching a video on YouTube about how $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(i)}{i} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$ (note that $\chi(i) = 0$ for even numbers $i$, $1$ for $\text{mod}(i, 4) = 1$, and $-1$ for $\text{mod}(i,4) = 3$) and one of the proofs shown involved stating that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(i)}{i} = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\chi(i+1)x^{i}dx\,.$$
My question is 1.) how is this done and 2.) how can this be replicated with different infinite sums. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that, for all $i\geq 1$,
$$\frac{1}{i} = \int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx$$
*(this is a "trick" worth knowing)*, and therefore
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(i)}{i} = 
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi(i)\int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx
= 
\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi(i)x^{i-1} dx
= 
\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty \chi(k+1)x^{k} dx
$$
where the only part which would require justification is when we swap $\int_0^1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$: this is Tonelli-Fubini.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a power series
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,a_kx^k$$
with radius of convergence $r\geq 1$ ($a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\in\mathbb{C}$), then $f_n|_{[0,1)}\to f|_{[0,1)}$ uniformly on compact sets as $n\to\infty$, where $$f_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n\,a_kx^k\text{ for each }x\in\mathbb{C}\text{ and }n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\,.$$
This provides a justification for swapping the infinite sum and the integral, that is,
$$\int_0^1\,f(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_0^1\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,a_kx^k\,\text{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\int_0^1\,a_kx^k\,\text{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{a_{k}}{k+1}\,.$$

---

In particular, the power series
$$g(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\chi(k+1)\,x^k$$
has radius of convergence $\dfrac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\,\sqrt[k]{\big|\chi(k+1)\big|}}=1$.  Therefore, you can swap the integral and the infinite sum to obtain
$$\int_0^1\,g(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_0^1\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\chi(k+1)\,x^k\,\text{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{\chi(k+1)}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{\chi(k)}{k}\,.$$

Note that $x^4\,g(x)=g(x)-1+x^2$, so $$g(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^4}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{C}\text{ such that }|x|<1\,.$$
That is,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{\chi(k)}{k}=\int_0^1\,\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\text{d}x=\arctan(x)\big|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\,.$$

---

Alternatively, note that
$$\chi(k)=\frac{\text{i}^k-(-\text{i})^k}{2\text{i}}\text{ for each }k=0,1,2,\ldots\,,$$
where $\text{i}$ is the imaginary unit $\sqrt{-1}$.  From the Taylor series of the principal branch of the natural logarithm function $$\ln(1+z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\,z^k\,,$$ we note that the series above converges for $z=\pm \text{i}$, yielding
$$\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(2)+\text{i}\frac{\pi}{4}=\ln(1+\text{i})=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{(-\text{i})^k}{k}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(2)-\text{i}\frac{\pi}{4}=\ln(1-\text{i})=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{\text{i}^k}{k}\,.$$
Subtracting the two equations above and dividing the result by $2\text{i}$ yields
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{\text{i}^k-(-\text{i})^k}{2\text{i}\,k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{\chi(k)}{k}\,.$$

Comment: For all this to work, you need to show that $g(1)$ converges and that seems to be the crux of the matter.

Comment: @Matematleta  No, I don't need to know that.  The integral can be viewed as the integral on the interval $[0,1)$.  The important thing is that $g(x)$ converges absolutely for $x\in[0,1)$, and that the partial sums of $g(x)$ converge to $g(x)$ uniformly on compact sets.  And in fact, $g(1)$ diverges.

Comment: Right. So, as it stands, $\int_0^1\,g(x)\,\text{d}x$ does not make sense. If you want to use the DCT, what is your dominating function?

Comment: @Matematleta  I wasn't using the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  It is a well known result that if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compact sets (i.e., $f_n$ compactly converges to $f$) and $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set of finite measure, then $\int_E\,f_n\to \int_E\,f$.  But sure, if you want to use that theorem, then you can take the dominating function to be $1$.  For all $x\in[0,1)$, $\big|g(x)\big|\leq 1$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I did not use the correct def of $\chi.$ As for the well-known result, yes I know it, and my question is how does it apply since the partial sums of $g$ do not even converge pointwise on the compact set $[0,1]$,never mind uniformly. (Convergence fails at $x=1.$)

Comment: I did not say that $g$ converges on $[0,1]$.  I said that the partial sums $g_n$ of $g$ converges to $g$ **uniformly on compact sets** (or $g_n$ **compactly converges to** $g$).  This is different from uniform convergence (that is what you were probably thinking).  That means, for any compact subset $K$ of the domain of definition of $g$, $g_n|_K\to g|_K$ uniformly.  You can take this domain of definition to be $[0,1)$.  And no matter what, the end point $\{1\}$ has measure $0$, so it never matters in the first place whether $g(1)$ is defined.

Comment: In fact, to use the "well-known result", you $must$ take your domain of definition to be $[0,1)$ because the partial sums $g_n$ do not converge to $g$ on the compact set $[0,1]$ (failure at $x=1$.) And in this case, the integral must either be understood as an improper Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral on which the DCT applies, not the "well-known result" you are using. Or what am I missing? Ugh...

Comment: You are still confused between the terms "uniformly convergent" and "uniformly convergent on compact sets (=compactly convergent)."  Maybe a Wiki link will help you understand what I am talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Forget for the moment uniform convergence. Take $E=[0,1]$ and apply the DCT to the Lebesgue integrals$\int_E g_n$. Fine. You are done. But to use the well-known result, you can't take $E=[0,1]$ because $g_n$ does not converge $pointwise$ on $[0,1]$ (which of course is a compact subset of $[0,1]$.) If you take $[0,1)$ then the result does apply, but now the integral is not well-defined in either the sense of  Lebesgue or that of Riemann . You need to calculate it as an improper integral,and that was my original point.

Comment: I never said I was taking $E=[0,1]$.  I told you I used $E:=[0,1)$.  You are the one who keeps saying it.  The integral is well defined in the Lebesgue sense, and in the Riemann sense by considering the integral as the integral on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ then take the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$.  And I'm sure you misunderstand the well known result I was citing.  The version for uniformly convergent sequences is probably what you keep thinking about.  I have been saying that the version I refer to is the one for compactly convergent sequences.

Comment: But I concede that if I want to use the Riemann approach, it has to be done with improper integrals.  But again, let me cite the theorem I am referring to.  $$\phantom{a}$$  **Theorem.**  Let $f$ be a Lebesgue-integrable function on a set $E$ of finite Lebesgue measure.  Suppose that $\left(f_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$ is a sequence of Lebesgue-integrable functions such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on each compact subset $K$ of $E$, as $n\to\infty$.  Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\int_E\,f_n=\int_E\,f\,.$$

Comment: All I am  saying is that the "well-known" result does not apply unless you are looking at $[0,1),$  and in this case, yes, as I said, the integral is defined (as you point out) as an improper Riemann integral, but this is NOT strictly speaking, a Riemann integral. It $is$ defined as a Lebesgue integral on $[0,1]$,which is the meaning of $\int^1_0 g$, and so the DCT applies. I am sorry if we talked past each other. It was not my intention to make such a mess of this. I will delete my comments after you have read this! And yes the theorem you cite is a well-known result!

Comment: I have read the last comment.  Whether you want to delete the discussion, it's up to you, but I think the discussion does contribute some values.  It allows me to clarify what exactly I was doing, and may be of use to other people.

Comment: Agreed. Cheers.